# How to set intervals for step-like plot (`const plot`) in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I set the precise intervals that pgfplots should consider when performing `addplot` with the option `const plot mark mid`? For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
1., 1.
2., 2.
4., 3.
7., 4.
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[const plot mark mid, mark=*] table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that when you have an input table which is irregular in the x-axis, pgfplots divides the intervals in a not so convenient way. It simply ends the "step" in the middle way to the next mid point. So, I would like to set the intervals by hand.

Output:

[image]

In this case, I would like to correct it by providing a **list of widths**

```
{1.,1.,3.,3.}
```

to cover the following intervals:

```
0.5 -- 1.5
1.5 -- 2.5
2.5 -- 5.5
5.5 -- 8.5
```

This way, the points would be exactly in the middle of the steps.

**Additional comment**

Pgfplots documentation says that one can avoid the vertical line being drawn in the middle way between two adjacent points, by using `jump mark mid`. In my example it would be

```
\addplot[jump mark mid, mark=*] table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
```

Nevertheless, this does not solve the problem, as the horizontal lines are kept identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with the following solution, which requires the inclusion of an additional column in the original table. Such additional column must contain the widths I referred in my question.

The code is divided in 3 distinct plots:

- marks for the original points;
- a `const plot` shifted (-) by half of the corresponding widths (black line);
  and
- a `jump mark right` shifted (+) by half width, for drawing the last step (dashed red line).

The last item requires ignoring most of the points in `data.csv` by using `skip coords between index={\yini}{\yfin}`. `\yini` and `yfin` are defined in an automatized way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
1., 1., 1.
2., 2., 1.
4., 3., 3.
7., 4., 3.
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yfin{\pgfmathresult-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yini{0}
%
\begin{axis}
[minor tick num=3]
%
\addplot[mark=*, only marks] 
table [col sep=comma,
x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]
{data.csv};
%
\addplot[const plot, black]
table [col sep=comma,
x expr=\thisrowno{0} - 0.5*\thisrowno{2}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]
{data.csv};
%
\addplot[jump mark right, red, ultra thick, dashed] 
table [col sep=comma,
x expr=\thisrowno{0} + 0.5*\thisrowno{2} , y expr=\thisrowno{1}, skip coords between index={\yini}{\yfin}] 
{data.csv};
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the solution code.]